# The URL is not working after running the container in Docker Toolbox

Tags: docker, url, docker-container

I pulled the docker container from the docker hub. After running the container, it gave me two links which should direct me to my desired page but both links show "the site can't be reached. I am using the following command: docker run 'name of the container'
I am working in the Docker toolbox in windows 10 home version.
Any help is highly appreciated

Answer (score 0):

few Things first, docker hub has images that you pull and then using those images you start a container.
to start a container using the command - `docker run -p 8080:8080 -d <image-name>`
here `-d` is for a detached container so that it does not stop with the shell.
and `-p` is port that you want to be linked to your localhost port.

Your container would be in running state. check by the command `docker ps`.

Hope this helps. First answer on StackOverflow.